# Regex return only last number after special char

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have totally 5 inputs like this,

```
A-01
AB - A2-01:xyz word (*)
AB - A3-02a:xyz word (*):xyz word (*)
AB - A-01:xyz word (*)
xyz-word  (*)
```

Trying to get only last number after the special character -

Expected result after applying regex:

```
01
01
02
01
empty(just return empty)
```

Regex:

```
const input2 = 'AB - A2-01:xyz word (*)';
console.log(input.match("[^-]+$")[0]);
```

**input.match("[^-]+$")[0]** regex works for first input **A-01**. It returns **01**.
For second input it prints as,
**01:xyz word (*)**.
After the number, I don't need the rest of the characters.

I am trying this in Angular TypeScript using regex.

Comment: All the examples look quite the same, with `-` immediately followed by two digits you want to get as result. Is that the pattern? If not, can you bring some variation in your examples?

Comment: `.*-[^\d]*(\d+).*` should capture the number after the last `-`. If the capture group is empty, there was no match. I have no idea how to translate that into javascript though

Comment: Perhaps using a capture group `.*-(\d+)[^\d\n]*$` https://regex101.com/r/ZrDkuD/1 or like `-(\d+)[^-\n]+$` https://regex101.com/r/lBVXLc/1

Comment: @trincot yes. I need two digits immediately followed by - as result. I got the answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will capture the first number after the last `-`:

```js
const inputs = ['A-01',
                'AB - A2-01:xyz word (*)',
                'AB - A3-02a:xyz word (*):xyz word (*)',
                'AB - A-01:xyz word (*)',
                'xyz-word  (*)'];

for (const input of inputs) {
    m = input.match(/^.*-[^\d]*(\d+)/);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[1]);
    }
}
```

The regex explained:

- `^` - start of line anchor
- `.*` - any character 0 or more times (greedy)
- `-` - a literal `-`
- `[^\d]*` - any non-digit, 0 or more times (greedy)
- `(` - start of capture group

  - `\d+` - any digit, 1 or more times
- `)` - end of capture group

You'll then find the captured number in `m[1]` (if any - check `m` first).

---

If you instead want an array where the non-matching entries are "empty" (undefined), you could `map` the inputs using an arrow function expression and use an empty `()` capture for the non-matches.

```js
const inputs = ['A-01',
                'AB - A2-01:xyz word (*)',
                'AB - A3-02a:xyz word (*):xyz word (*)',
                'AB - A-01:xyz word (*)',
                'xyz-word  (*)'];

a = inputs.map(input => input.match(/^.*-[^\d]*(\d+)|()/)[1]);
console.log(a);
```

<sub>Disclaimer: This is my first javascript ever so I may have done it in a cumbersome, non-idiomatic, way</sub>